# intercepting and modifying XMLHttpRequests

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I'm writing an extension to let users intercept any ajax request and let them modify it. The code below works. It will intercept both xmlhttprequest open/send and prompt me with a dialog. The problem is that I am using prompt() in the xmlhttprequest.open instead of the promptOpen() method I was expecting it to work with. I am wondering if anyone has a clue on what I would need to do to get it to work.

```
(function(){

    async function promptSend(data){
        return new Promise(function(resolve){
            var swalConfig = {
                html: `<textarea id="swal-input1" class="" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>`,
                focusConfirm: false,
                preConfirm: () => {
                    resolve([document.getElementById("swal-input1").value])
                },
                onBeforeOpen: () => {
                    document.getElementById("swal-input1").value = data[0];

                },
                showCancelButton: false,
                allowOutsideClick: false
            };

            try{
                Swal.getQueueStep(); 
                Swal.insertQueueStep(swalConfig)
            }catch(e){
                Swal.queue([swalConfig])            
            }

        });
    }

    async function promptOpen(data){
        return new Promise(function(resolve){
            var swalConfig = {
                html: `<label for='swal-input1'>Method</label><input name='swal-input1' id='swal-input1' style='width:100%'><br><br>`+
                      `<label for='swal-input2'>Url</label><input name='swal-input2' id='swal-input2' style='width:100%'>`,
                focusConfirm: false,
                preConfirm: () => {
                    resolve([document.getElementById("swal-input1").value,document.getElementById("swal-input2").value])
                },
                onBeforeOpen: () => {
                    document.getElementById("swal-input1").value = data[0];
                    document.getElementById("swal-input2").value = data[1];
                },
                showCancelButton: false,
                allowOutsideClick: false
            };

            try{
                Swal.getQueueStep();
                Swal.insertQueueStep(swalConfig)
            }catch(e){
                Swal.queue([swalConfig])            
            }
        })

    }


    // Intercepts all XmlHttpRequest.open calls
    var proxiedOpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {

        //let newArguments = await promptOpen(arguments)
        arguments[0] = prompt("Enter Method",arguments[0])
        arguments[1] = prompt("Enter Url",arguments[1])

        return proxiedOpen.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    }


    // Intercepts all XmlHttpRequest.send calls
    var proxiedSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = async function() {

        let newArgument = await promptSend(arguments);
        arguments[0] = newArgument[0];

        return proxiedSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    }

})()
```

Any attempt I make at trying to convert it to promptOpen will result in the executed ajax call calling /undefined or not calling at all.

I tried the most obvious approach by turning it into an async function and using await such as how xmlhttprequest.send works.

```
var proxiedOpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = async function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    let newArguments = await promptOpen(arguments)
    arguments[0] = newArguments[0]
    arguments[1] = newArguments[1]

    return proxiedOpen.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
}
```

but as I said, it does not do any ajax request at all and does not even prompt the xmlhttprequest.send box.